# Jquery Animate not working but run console

Tags: jquery, console, jquery-animate

Sorry, I can't speak English so excuse me. I have object 'window.userInterface.filmMakinesi'. I this object run console no problem. But when run my javascript file create a problem occurs. Not working. Interesting.

```
    window.userInterface.filmMakinesi = function(control) {

        controlBox                  = [];
        controlBox["ileri"]     = {dinamikCSS: "top",operator:"-"};
        controlBox["geri"]      = {dinamikCSS: "bottom",operator:"+"};

        secim       = controlBox[control].dinamikCSS;
        operator    = controlBox[control].operator;
        height      = parseInt($("section.open").height());
        /*
        secim : top;
  operator: -
  height: 270;
  */
        $("div#filmMakinesi").animate({ secim : operator+height+"px"},600,"swing"); 
    }
window.userInterface.filmMakinesi("geri");
```

NOT WORKİNG BUT HOW IT WORKS.  String instead of trying I wrote the value.

```
    window.userInterface.filmMakinesi = function(control) {

        controlBox                  = [];
        controlBox["ileri"]     = {dinamikCSS: "top",operator:"-"};
        controlBox["geri"]      = {dinamikCSS: "bottom",operator:"+"};

        secim       = controlBox[control].dinamikCSS;
        operator    = controlBox[control].operator;
        height      = parseInt($("section.open").height());

        //                              \/\/\/

        $("div#filmMakinesi").animate({ "top" : operator+height+"px"},600,"swing"); 
    }
window.userInterface.filmMakinesi("geri");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an object so you can use `[]` notation to allow using variable `secim` as a dynamic property.

```
var animateObject = {};
animateObject[secim] = operator+height+"px";
$("div#filmMakinesi").animate(animateObject ,600,"swing");
```

You can not create the property `foo` this way:

```
   var myVariable = 'foo';
   var object = { myVariable :'some value'};
   console.log(object.foo) // returns undefined
   console.log(object.myVariable ) // returns 'some value'
```